# Excel VBA userform type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

First time asking a question here, my apologies if my question has already been answered (If it was, I didn't understand it because **I am an utter novice**). My Excel userform that I use to update quantities of stock supplies used on a particular job is generating a

> type mismatch error

It is supposed to add the quantity from the useform to the entry in the appropriate cell on the sheet. I assume that this has something to do with a variable not being declared correctly.

```
Private Sub SubmitFormButton_Click()

Dim Data_Start As Range

Dim i As Integer

Set Data_Start = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 6)

For i = 1 To 31

    Data_Start.Offset(i, 0) = Data_Start.Offset(i, 0) + AddToform.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value

Next i

Unload AddToform

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you entering the number on your userform??

Comment: which line does the error occur on?

Comment: If this code runs from within the form then change `AddToform` to `Me` so that it references the current instance of the form.

Comment: You should probably be using `+ Val(AddToform.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value)` to convert the textbox values to true numbers. Technically `CDbl` would be more appropriate if you might not be dealing with US settings but `Val` works better with empty textboxes.

Comment: Val or CDbl wouldn't be required if a number is entered into the TextBox. The Mismatch error will only be produced if the TextBox is empty and in that case Val(AddToform.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value) would be enough to deal with this error.

Comment: @sktneer I'd generally agree but if the cell contained text already (eg wrong cell, or bad data entry) then not using `Val` would cause the `+` to operate like `&` and simply append the data. Using `Val`/`CDbl` would *cause* an error, which would probably be a good thing.

Comment: Honorable mention to those who suggested using Val(), which worked as well with the addition of a conditional to test if the field had been left empty. Ultimately, I used Mat's Mug's suggestion because it had the added benefit of validating whether the entry was numeric. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddToform.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value` is making a number of assumptions:

- `AddToForm` was shown with `AddToForm.Show`. If you're doing this:

  ```
  With New AddToForm
      .Show
      '...
  End With
  ```

  ...then the code is not referring to the *instance* that's being displayed, and the `.Value` of the textbox is very likely not what you expect it to be, since the textbox you're reading from isn't the textbox that the user entered a value in.
- There's a control named `"TextBox" & i` on the form. This means if you ever rename your textboxes to more meaningful names, e.g. `FirstNameBox`, `LastNameBox` (or whatever makes sense), then the code breaks. Using control names to hold metadata (e.g. some worksheet row number offset) can work, but it's probably better to iterate the controls on the form (whatever their names are), test if the current control is a `TextBox` (e.g. `If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then`), and then pull the metadata from the control's `Tag` property. That way your controls can have meaningful names *and* renaming them won't break any of the logic.
- User input is valid. That's always a bad assumption to make, regardless of the language or technology being used: *always* protect your code from invalid input. If the user enters "ABC", that loop breaks. One way to do this, is to introduce a local variable, to separate *getting the user input* from *consuming the user input* - and validate it on the way:

  ```
  If IsNumeric(Controls("TextBox" & i).Value) Then
      Dim validInput As Double
      validInput = CDbl(Controls("TextBox" & i).Value)
      Data_Start.Offset(i, 0) = Data_Start.Offset(i, 0) + validInput
  End If
  ```

  And that should fix your bug.

Comment: Thanks, I ready the article, and I aspire to comprehend it someday!